# Including #include files at the end

Tags: c

I had an interview question where the interviewer asked me what error would we get from the below output:

```
int main()
{    
    printf("hello world");
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
```

I answered "no error" and it will display the output.

can anyone help me with this???

Please note"the missing angular brackets is intentionally done by me so dont bother about that"

Comment: printf method is not declared anywhere, in C that would emit a warning.

Comment: If I understood it right, when you include a library, you are actually include the code, so the definition of the printf is not visible before

Comment: Write the program, compile and see! Can it be more difficult than that... http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

Comment: My comment of course is not 100 % completly correct, but it gives the idea

Comment: @hackworks: I already wrote and compiled the program long before posting the question and even got the output with no errors.. I was still a bit confused so i posted the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the compiler.

Most C compilers will *probably* accept that code (perhaps with a warning) and produce an executable that prints the expected output.

Under C90 rules, the behavior of the `printf` call is undefined; it's invalid to call a variadic function with no visible prototype. Variadic functions can have a different calling convention from ordinary functions, and you have to let the compiler know that `printf` is variadic so it can generate correct code for the call.

Under C99 and later rules, calling any function with no visible declaration (which may or may not be a prototype) is a *constraint violation*, requiring at least a compile-time warning.

The standard doesn't hint at what happens if you call `printf` without the required prototype, but in practice most compilers will handle it "correctly".

The missing `'\n'` at the end of the output means that the program's behavior is undefined *if* the implementation requires a newline at the end of the output; whether that's required or not is implementation-defined. In any case, adding a newline is a good idea.

The `#include <stdio.h>` at the end of the source file should be useless but harmless.

I'm assuming that the source file actually contains `#include <stdio.h>` and not `#include stdio.h`; the latter would be a syntax error.

(Practically speaking, of course, the `#include <stdio.h>` *should* be at the top. In a professional setting, the output is irrelevant, since the program will never survive a code review.)

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error for missing quotes or `<>` in the filename for the `#include`. It should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Apart from that, it should compile with a warning about an implicit declaration to `printf()`. On Clang, it gives me:

```
test.c:3:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'
    printf("hello world");
    ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @EdS. Implicitly declaring a function is not in the list of what I would call a good practice, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

When your `main()` function is being declared, the compiler will run into the first line of `main()` and it will have no idea what `printf()` is. You will get an error about the compiler complaining about an undeclared function.

Assuming, of course, the missing `<` and `>` was a mistake introduced when you copied your question over.

Comment: but doesnt preprocessor check the entire source code and processes all #includes before reaching the compilation stage??

Comment: The pre-processor does a single pass on the file. Had it done a 2 pass pre-processing, it would have been able to resolve all such symbols since it found it later in the file. Most linkers do a 2 pass linking to handle cross library symbol references. Read the book 'Linkers & Loaders' (http://www.amazon.com/Linkers-Kaufmann-Software-Engineering-Programming/dp/1558604960), worth it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors here.  The first is that the include directive must happen before the code that requires that header information, in this case printf() is declared in stdio.h, and the second is that the filename in the include directive must be enclosed in angle brackets, <>, or quotes, "".

Comment: they were angular brackets but it was not displaying while posting the question..and when i compiled the program, it showed me the output.

Comment: OK, it must have removed them to prevent cross-site scripting.  So just the one error, printf() is undefined until after the include directive for stdio.h